# Compiling C++ OpenCV project in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation

A few days ago I downloaded a C++ project for OpenCV (https://github.com/aishack/sift).

As it needs OpenCV to be run, I installed it following the steps in here (http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/).

I guess the installation went well as I've been running some examples which work prefectly fine.

My problem comes when I try to compile the project I downloaded. I'm working on ubuntu, so I have to compile it for Ubuntu.

I'd also like to compile it from the command line, but I've spent some days trying to do so but I can't. It's frustating.

I hope someone with experience in OpenCV will help me. Thanks.

EDIT: (errors translated to english)

> ```
> CMakeFiles/demo.dir/MySIFT.cpp.o: In function 'main':
> MySIFT.cpp:(.text+0x2b): reference to `SIFT::SIFT(char const*, int, int)' not defined
>
> MySIFT.cpp:(.text+0x3b): reference to `SIFT::DoSift()' not defined
>
> MySIFT.cpp:(.text+0x47): reference to `SIFT::ShowAbsSigma()' not defined
>
> MySIFT.cpp:(.text+0x53): reference to `SIFT::ShowKeypoints()' not defined
>
> MySIFT.cpp:(.text+0x6e): reference to `SIFT::~SIFT()' not defined
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> CMakeFiles/demo.dir/build.make:111: fail in instruction for objective  'demo'
> make[2]: *** [demo] Error 1
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: fail in instruction for objective 'CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all'
>
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
>
> Makefile:83: fail in instruction for objective 'all'
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

Comment: @Rakete1111 Sorry, forgot to append errors in the question.